# XSLT: getting the content of an element and putting it somewhere else

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I would need some help with my XSL Transformation. It is an XML to XML transformation.

I have this XML structure:

```
<book>
    <chap>
        <dev>
            <p>This is some text<apnb id="N1">blah blah blah</p>
            <p>...</p>
            <p>...</p>
            <quote>...</quote>
        </dev>
        <defnotes>
            <ntb id="N1">This is the footnote corresponding to the element apnb</ntb>
        </defnotes>
    </chap>
</book>
```

With an XSLT transformation, I need to put the content of the `ntb` element into a note element that will replace the `apnb` element, directly inside the paragraph. My attempt was to create an `xsl:variable name="N1"` to put the text of the ntb `id="N1"` element, and then create the note element where appropriate and put `xsl:value-of select="$N1"`. But it doesn't work. I think my XPATH expression probably is wrong (as I am quite a beginner with XSLT).

I hope you understand my problem. Thanks in advance for all your answers.

Flo

Comment: _apnb_ isn't an element! Please post your expected output and the tried XSLT here so that we could help you.

Comment: please also add the xslt version you use or you want to use

Comment: Welcome. There are lots of people here happy to help debug your XSLT code. But first they need to see your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath should be something like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//ntb[@id='N1']" />
```

That finds all ntb elements that have an attribute id that equal 'N1'.
This should work if you do not have duplicates names 'N1'.

Also, your XML for the apnb tag is invalid since it is missing the closing tag.

Your code here:

```
<apnb id="N1">
```

should be:

```
<apnb id="N1"/>
```

Comment: Thank you ! Actually, the Xpath you gave me works and will solve my problem. You were right about the apnb tag, I forgot to put the closing tag. Sorry about that.